# How far should we go to demonstrate a topic that could be used for harm?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, acceptable-answer

Whilst writing [an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work/18557#18557) recently, I had to ponder how much of the subject I should demonstrate, in terms of a real exploit scenario. In the case of the answer I wrote, I think that we're relatively safe since the demonstrated exploit was on a fictional piece of code.

However, we're bound to get situations in future where people ask about specific vulnerabilities. Should we give them full answers, with near-tutorial levels of detail, or should we provide more vague information that fits most scenarios?

Here's my thoughts so far:

- Single-vulnerability questions should be closed as Too Localized, unless they're high profile and warrant a decent writeup on the subject.
- Knowledge is inherently amoral. What's done with it is outside our jurisdiction. However, in cases where malintent is shown, we should close the question.
- Generic advice is useful to lots of people, but less useful to the asker. We'd have to judge this on a case-by-case basis. Should we have a line in the sand, or should we leave it up to the answerer to judge?

I'd like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Read also: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/897/485 and http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/903/485

Comment: @RoryAlsop Those were the questions I had in mind when writing this. I advise everyone to go read them, as they provide a good basis for a proper policy on this.

Comment: Related:  http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/117/should-we-allow-questions-answers-that-appear-to-include-or-request-exploit-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to give my opinions on the three points you have stated.

> Single-vulnerability questions should be closed as Too Localized, unless they're high profile and warrant a decent writeup on the subject.

I do not agree with this, coming from personal experiences.

[Understanding a vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15436/understanding-a-vulnerability)

This is my first question on Sec.SE. I was searching high and low for information on this particular vulnerability in the CVD and other similar databases. However, what I could find was either too vague, or too in-depth for someone of my experience.

I asked the question here and learnt plenty from the answer provided. The answerer was you no less. ;) This was what prompted me to stick around.

Going by your guidelines, I would have closed that question. Although it is a chrome vulnerability, it isn't particularly high profile. I don't think that is a good idea.

What we can do is enforce naming guidelines on the questions, which will provide the CVE number and other minor details. This would make searching for a information on a particular vulnerability easier.

> Knowledge is inherently amoral. What's done with it is outside our jurisdiction. However, in cases where malintent is shown, we should close the question.

I agree with this. Questions asking for explanations or clarifications about a particular vulnerability should be allowed. However, questions like "give me the exploit code for this vulnerability pl0x" should be closed immediately.

> Generic advice is useful to lots of people, but less useful to the asker. We'd have to judge this on a case-by-case basis. Should we have a line in the sand, or should we leave it up to the answerer to judge?

I don't think it is possible to provide a guideline for this. It will vary from question to question. The answerer should decide on what to cover. Upvotes and downvotes by the community will do the rest.

Comment: +1. Very good points. I had not considered that Chrome question when I asked this. Perhaps the line in terms of answering should be "don't provide direct details of exploitability or working shellcode for vulnerabilities".